# I need to generate new workbooks using existing sheets that I will autopop with data

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets on my template. Sheet one contains a SKU in column A and a descr. in column B

On sheet 2, I have a pre-written template that has generic SKU and Description. That means under the item sku, it says D999 and under the description it says xxx.

I want to replace "999" with the value in A2 on my first sheet, but the 999 is in multiple columns through the sheet. Next, I want to replace the "xxx" with the data in B2 from sheet 1. I can't seem to find a VBA code that will do this specifically.

Lastly, once the find and replaces are done, I need to have it save me a new workbook using sheet2, in the same format, and name it as the value in A4 on sheet 2. I think you should be able to find the workbook here [My Workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vbs3su3772f5qn/Vinyl%20Color%20Variation%20Template.txt?dl=0)

Basically, I want to be able to enter a bulk amount of new SKUs and Description, and be able to generate a new workbook for each SKU I enter. Right now I have 78 waiting to have sheets made.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write the code for you? It is helpful if you show what you have tried so others can build and revise.

Comment: I don't have any code because when I go to re-name the sheet, I don't know how to do it regularly so how could I record that? The only way I have found to re-name a sheet is manually and I cannot source a cell in the sheet as the name. I have to manually type it. However, if I could get the find and replace to work, we could actually have the new workbook save and source the name of the file off of a cell, if that was possible?

Comment: I have zero experience in VBA. The only macro's I have made have been done through the record function.

Answer (score 0):

In the cell  to the right of the cells where you want to type in the SKU, add the following formula: =Match(A2, LookupsheetName!B:B,0). This will return the row the SKU was found on. In the next cell to the right use the Index function: =Index(LookupSheetName!A1:B1000, B2, 0). This will bring the label in column B to the current page. The Match function locates the row the SKU was found on.

Try these for looking up the information, because they are more efficient than VLookups.

The code for copying a worksheet to another workbook can be created using the Macro recorder on the Developer tab. Turn the recorder on then do the steps to manually move/copy to another workbook. When done, open the VBA editor and figure out how to save the workbook to a new name each time.

Good luck.

Comment: I can't add the formula's to that sheet because that sheet get's uploaded and cannot be changed.

Comment: Programmatically load the column, then when done, delete the column before uploading.